# Sax parser not getting full text, no unallowed or ampersand chars

Tags: android, xml, sax, saxparser

```
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                             Attributes attributes) {
        elementOn = true;
        if (localName.equals("DEAL")) {
            discount = new Discount();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName){
        elementOn = false;
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("IMAGE")) {
            discount.setImage(elementValue);
        } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("DEAL")) {
            arrayDiscount.add(discount);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length){

        if (elementOn) {
            elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            elementOn = false;
        }

    }
```

and then input looks like (I paste only the a few lines, there is also many lines before and after, many, objects" containing IMAGE, PRICES and other tags)

```
<IMAGE>http://www.url.com/1815/e0deb0bcca75704ef974d017028563f401386541247.jpg</IMAGE>
<FINAL_PRICE>24.9</FINAL_PRICE>
<ORIGINAL_PRICE>49</ORIGINAL_PRICE>
```

when I then put to console output from the arrays of discounts and get image url, it gives me sometimes only parts of that string like

**http://www.url.com/1815/e0deb0bcc**

IT happened only in long text between open and enclosing tags
Here is also connecting SaxParser

```
SAXParserFactory saxPF = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxP = saxPF.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xmlR = saxP.getXMLReader();
URL url = new URL("http://www.url.com/output.xml");
XMLHandler myXMLHandler = new XMLHandler();
xmlR.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
xmlR.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
```

Im using Sax Parser because it is the fastes from the native classes of Android.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The SAX interface allows a parser to break a text node up into multiple pieces and supply the pieces in multiple calls of the characters() method. Your code is not allowing for this possibility. The parser is allowed to break the text anywhere, but it is common practice to break it in places where the text content is not contiguous in the input, e.g. at entity boundaries.